# get() for default values in Pandas Series, using position

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to get a default value, when accessing a row by position? I am aware of the `.get()` function, but that works when searching by index.

Below is what I want to do. The DataFrame:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
    col1
idx
20     A
21     B
22     C
23     D
24     E
```

Searching by index and getting a default value works fine:

```
In [25]: df['col1'].get(23, 'the_default_value')
Out[25]: 'D'

In [26]: df['col1'].get(28, 'the_default_value')
Out[26]: 'the_default_value'
```

But there doesn't appear to be an equivalent way to search by position. I can use `.iloc()`, but it doesn't help in getting a default value if that row is not present. Eg.

```
In [57]: df['col1'].iloc[2]
Out[57]: 'C'

In [58]: df['col1'].iloc[6]
...
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I can set it up using `try...except`, or check beforehand if the value exists or not, but is there a cleaner way of doing it, like `.iget()` (like the `.loc` vs `.iloc`)?

Comment: You could just reset the index so it starts from `0`

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But if I need the actual index, it will just mean going back and forth resetting the index (one of the uses is inside a loop).

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this be considered cleaner:

```
df['new_index'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
df = df.set_index('new_index')

df['col1'].get(2, 'the_default_value')
```

If the original index is required, then, it may be useful to use multi-index

```
df['new_index'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
df = df.set_index('new_index', append=True)

df['col1'].get((pd.IndexSlice[:], 2), 'the_default_value')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like it is getting more complex in readability. I think in your first solution, you also need to get rid of the original index for it to work - in which case it is easier to just do `df.reset_index()`. But I am trying to avoid changing the index.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got another answer:

```
n = 2
df['col1'].get(df.index[n] if n < df.shape[0] else None, 'hi')
```

So,  use get with positional values into the index...